# Prevent range slider handlers from crossing each other (material-ui/ reactjs)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using [Material-UI's range slider](https://codesandbox.io/s/xqcfl?file=/demo.tsx) and noticed it allows crossing and overlapping.

[image: handlers crossing and overlapping each other]

Is there a way to prevent the handlers from crossing and overlapping each other?

For instance, rc-slider library has a prop "allowCross" which has exactly the behavior I want when it's set to false. However, I need it to be implemented using Material UI's Slider component.

[image: handlers not crossing and not overlapping each other]

Comment: Material-UI v4 does not have this feature, but v5 (currently in beta) does via the `disableSwap` prop (https://next.material-ui.com/components/slider/#minimum-distance).

Comment: @RyanCogswell that's amazing, thank you for your comment! That will do in my case